# The method that sends e-mail works, but how to prevent the amount of spam received emails come?

Tags: android, email, smtp, jms, spam-prevention

I have a method that sends email in back ground that works well, but I need to find a way that as the amount of incoming emails do not see spam. Already researched the JMS framework (Java Message Service) but not found a way to make this work and did not find an example.

The idea is to call this frame work and spend the SMTP within it.

If you can show an example I will be grateful.

Recalling that the method works well, but what if in case an e-mail to receive more than 10,000 emails for example, could go to spam. So I wanted to find a way that does not happen.

Below is the method I use to send the email in back ground:

```
ui.btnEnviarPedidoParaEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                rec = "";
                subject = "Pedido Solicitado";
                textMessage = "Nome: " + ui.nome.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Rua: " + ui.rua.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Número: " + ui.numero.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Complemento: " + ui.complemento.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Bairro: " + ui.bairro.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "CEP: " + ui.cep.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Telefone: " + ui.telefone1.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Celular: " + ui.telefone2.getText() +
                        "<br />" + "Valor total do Pedido: " + CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(valorDoPedido)) +
                        "<br />" + "-------------------------------" +
                        "<br />" + "Lista de itens solicitados:" +
                        "<br />" + "Produto: " + nomeDoProduto +
                        "<br />" + "Descrição: " + descricaoDoProduto +
                        "<br />" + "Preço unitário: " + CurrencyUtils.format(BigDecimal.valueOf(precoUnitarioDoProduto)) +
                        "<br />" + "Quantidade :" + quantidadeDoProduto;


                Properties props = new Properties();

                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

                session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
                    @Override
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("", "");
                    }
                });

                pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Enviando o pedido para o email...", true);

                RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
                task.execute();

            }

            class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    try {
                        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(""));
                        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
                        message.setSubject(subject);
                        message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

                        Transport.send(message);
                    } catch (MessagingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pedido enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: Do not understand the problem. If you send 10 000 emails from Android, you should start to think that an Android platform is not made to create a server... Anyway, I don't understand what is your problem

Comment: The problem is that if there are many requests, emails can stop the spam, because I use my own email in the background to send requests for mail.

Comment: It sounds like you are actually sending spam, and the spam blockers are doing their job. Why does this have to be done by email?

Comment: When i send an email, i can get it normal. The problem is to avoid spam with the amount of emails sent over time, this would be a case of prevention.
I did not find another way to communicate with the user by messages.